# Pyspark derive average based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have student IDs and the rates (evaluation of students) for each year year. I want to calculate the average-rate between training start-date and end-date (when start and end rows are populated and not null): `average-rate = average(start-date.rate, between rates...end-date)`. Let me explain more:

This is my data :

```
ID  Year     rate      start-date      end-date
1   2015      2          2015           2017
8   2012      3          2010           2012
7   2007      12          Null          2008
1   2016      4           2015          2017
8   2010      7          2010           2012
9   2002      10          2002          null
1   2015      2          2015           2017
1   2017      8          2015           2017
8   2011      3          2010           2012
```

In this table ideally:

- Delete `ID7` and `ID9` cause of null value in dates cells ( because we cant'find an average related to the training).
- Duplicated rows ( like the two rows in the bottom of the table) will be reduced to one unique row.
- Calculate the average_rate for example for `ID1`. The start_date is 2015 and the end date is 2017. So we will need to average the rates for (2015,2016 and 2017) from column tow and column three. 
  So for ID1:

```
2015 rate = 2
2016 rate = 4
2017 rate = 8
average-rate = (14/3 = 4.66)
```

The output table will be

```
ID   avarage_rate
1     4.66
8     4.33
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try anything? This looks easy as per your description. Something like `df.filter("start_date is not null and end_date is not null").distinct.groupBy("id").agg(avg(col("rate")).alias("rate") )` should do the trick

Comment: Yes this look very easy ... but what about start and end dates ?

Comment: What about them? They don't exist in your output table.

Comment: the avarage rate dont necessary require all the rates corresponding to the the groupBy you see ? we might have 5 ID's after the group by but we need only 3 IDs (corresponding to the start and end dates) to average.

Comment: because I dropped the dates in the final output...

Comment: One student with the same ID can have 100 rates, I dont need to average them all ! I just need to average the rates between start and end dates

Comment: Remove all rows with a year not between start and end using `filter`.

Comment: Ah for each ID ?

Comment: You'll need to give us a more concrete example than this. How do you know which start and end date to consider? In your example, the start and end dates for ID1 and ID8 are the same in all rows? Can there be a scenario where that won't be the case? What will be the output in that case?

Comment: last row is not a duplicate ...

Comment: The row before the last one I mean ID1

Comment: @Lizou you haven't answered philantrovert's question yet.

Comment: Hi @philantrovert,

Comment: Hi @philantrovert, The ID's are student ID's, the rates are the student evaluation and the start-year and end-year are: start_year: the first year the student attend the training and end_year: when he ended the training. So for each student, the start and end year are the same they will never change. I want to compute the average rate for each student from start year to end_year. It is the average of all rate of each year starting from start_year to end_year. To do this, Ideally one needs to group the students by ID's and ascending dates.

Comment: Then, the average rate is computed with respect of the start_date and end_date.

Comment: What I have done in the beginning is to groupBy ID and then simply average the rates! however, I discovered that some rate does not correspond to the start end dates. Let's say the student started on 2010 and finished on 2015 but has a rate in 2008, I should not take this rate into consideration. I just need to select the rates between 2010 and 2015 and average only these. Thanks